# How to convert table td inline style width pt to convert percentage to suit for responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<table>
 <tr style="height:15pt;">
      <td style="width:229pt;border-style:solid;border-width:0pt;padding:3pt 9pt 3pt 0pt;" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#c0c0c0"><p style="font-family:Times New Roman, serif;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;text-indent:-14pt;margin:0 0 0 14pt;" align="left">Compensation: </p></td>
      <td style="width:33pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;padding:3pt 0pt 3pt 0pt;" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#c0c0c0"></td>
      <td style="width:6pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;padding:3pt 0pt 3pt 0pt;" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#c0c0c0"></td>
      <td style="width:33pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;padding:3pt 0pt 3pt 0pt;" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#c0c0c0"></td>
      <td style="width:32pt;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;padding:3pt 0pt 3pt 0pt;" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#c0c0c0"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

want to convert style width "PT" to percentage to suit all resolution.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table{width:100%}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr style="height:15pt;">
      <td style="width:68%;border-style:solid;border-width:0pt;padding:3pt 9pt 3pt 0pt;" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#c0c0c0"><p style="font-family:Times New Roman, serif;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;text-indent:-14pt;margin:0 0 0 14pt;" align="left">Compensation: </p></td>
      <td style="width:10%;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;padding:3pt 0pt 3pt 0pt;" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#c0c0c0"></td>
      <td style="width:2%;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;padding:3pt 0pt 3pt 0pt;" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#c0c0c0"></td>
      <td style="width:10%;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;padding:3pt 0pt 3pt 0pt;" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#c0c0c0"></td>
      <td style="width:10%;border-style:solid;border-width:1pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;padding:3pt 0pt 3pt 0pt;" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#c0c0c0"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Selva Balaji try above

Comment: It will be automatic conversion on all the table td from the page.

Comment: Total 100% width. but td total width was 102% ?

Comment: How to say td total width was 102%. Resize your browser to check it. It will work fine.

Comment: width:70%;

width:10%
width:2% width:10% width:10%                ------------ Total 102%

Comment: Wheather you are using any formula ?

Comment: No You have to split 100% of parent element to inner elements like all child td elemnt width:68%; width:10% width:2% width:10% width:10% and parent element tabel is 100%

Comment: @Selva Balaji now understand.